# is it easier to rent a car with a secured credit card over a debit card?

Tags: car, debit-card, social-security, unemployment, secured-credit-card

I've been denied car rentals using debit cards in the past, even with thousands of dollars on the card.

I'm going to Hawaii as well as Tennessee this year, and will need a car. Would my odds increase if I got a secured credit card?

Also, would I be denied a secured card if I'm currently on unemployment?  My husband gets SSA and may have a better chance.  If he qualified for a secured card, would I be able to have a 2nd card with my name on it as well?

Comment: "I've been denied car rentals using debit cards in the past, even with thousands of dollars on the card."  The rental company does not know how much is in your checking account.

Comment: "Would my odds increase if I got a secured credit card?"  Maybe; the limit on secured cards tends to be low, so the rental company might balk; it can't hurt to ask them...  (As a side note, this is yet another example of why "I never use credit cards!" is foolish.  You can march to the beat of your own drum until there comes a time when you **really** need to march to march to everyone else's drum, and then it's too late.)

Comment: just one point, "If he qualified for a secured card, would I be able to have a 2nd card with my name on it as well?"  yes

Comment: its a really interesting question whether a *Secured* styl;e credit card, works as well at car rentals, as a normal credit card.  I don't know.